# How to determine which class causes the "java.io.InvalidClassException" - "local class incompatible"?

Tags: java, serialization

How to determine which serializable class causes above exception.
I tried to read the stack trace, but it is not clear for me...
I'm not familiar with the project very well.
Thank you!

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: ...and where is that stacktrace!!

Answer (score 2):

From `java.io.InvalidClassException` javaDoc:

```
 String     getMessage()
      Produce the message and include the classname, if present.
```

`getMessage()` should tell you the name of the offending class.